# Can't set value in modal after first page of datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, bootstrap-modal

I was trying to show list of users in my table and besides that i was trying to update individual user info with bootstrap modal. for that i passed user_id with following way to set into input field.

```
 <button  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myCoupon" class="btn btn-primary updateCoupon"  data-id="{{$user->id}}">Update Coupon</button><br>

$(function () {
        $(".updateCoupon").click(function () {
            var my_id_value = $(this).data('id');
            $(".modal-body #hiddenCoupon").val(my_id_value);
        })
    });

<input  id="hiddenCoupon" name="id" value="" type="hidden">
```

But for the first 10 rows of datatable i could set the id input field but for the next page of datatables it can't set. How to load the datatables with value so that i could easily set into modal input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".updateCoupon").on('click', function () {
        var my_id_value = $(this).data('id');
        $(".modal-body #hiddenCoupon").val(my_id_value);
    })
});
```

Comment: Nothing changed actually.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine my side. check are you getting {{$user->id}} parameter for all the rows?

Comment: Yes there is $user->id , did you check with datatables with pagination?

Comment: yes i have checked it with datatable with pagination.

Comment: I checked with different project as well ..in form it can't get the data-id

Answer (score 0):

Seems that $(".updateCoupon") doesn't exist on next pages upon DataTable generation. Try this:

```
$('#your_table_id').on('click', '.updateCoupon', function() {
  var my_id_value = $(this).data('id');
  // etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define the click event after dataTable rendered even after visting to next page in pagination. 
**Try this with dataTable callback:**

```
var myTable;

myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columnDefs,
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
       $(".updateCoupon").click(function () {
          var my_id_value = $(this).data('id');
          $(".modal-body #hiddenCoupon").val(my_id_value);
       });
     }
});
```

I have also created a fiddle. [please see this link](http://jsfiddle.net/nehadhiman6/bbLjzspf/3447/).